# Comparison of medians in samples with unequal variance, size and shape

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, mean, median, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

## What am I trying to do and how does my data look?

I am trying to perform some comparisons of medians of groups of data that, most often than not, are *not*-normally distributed. In some cases I am comparing some groups with 100-200 data points, but in others I'd like to compare groups with as little as 4 vs 10 data points if possible. Practically all of the compared groups have unequal sample size.

## How am I doing this?

To this regard, I am doing the following:

1. Using the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to compare the shape of the two samples (i.e. testing whether `data1` exhibits a distribution that follows that of `data2`; In Mathematica: `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data1,data2]`);
2. If shape is statistically similar, I use the Mann-Whitney U test to compare medians;
3. In most cases, groups do not have statistically similar shape. I therefore would like to perform a t-test with Welch correction (as [suggested in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38902/59647) and in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test)). However, this has not been implemented in Mathematica and I currently do not have the time to do it myself.

I understand that by shifting to the Welch t-test I am no longer comparing medians but means, but I would do this if no other option is available.

## Questions:

- Is there other test for comparing medians between samples with unequal variance, shape and size?
- What is the minimum sample size that I could take? I am aware that no minimal sample size exists for t-tests, because it depends on the power of the analysis. But maybe comparing shapes of distributions of 4 vs 10 points is not very good... And in such cases, the Central Limit Theorem should not have a very strong effect
- Anyone aware of such implementation in mathematica? Or maybe how to perform a Welch t-test there?

P.S. - I have searched a lot, including in this forum, but nothing shows up in this regard. I am truly sorry if this question was already answered before.

## Additional Information:

In the comments it was asked some additional information. I hope this all makes sense, and I'm sorry if I cannot provide higher context into our real question.

- The information for each sample was collected from the genomic composition of many organisms. So I have two lists of independent samples in the form `(0.01,0.7,0.15,...)` whose distribution I do not expect to follow any particular trend (i.e. Normal, Log-normal, etc).
- For each organism we have the whole frequencies, and not only a sample, but for the groups to compare: we only have a small sample. Ideally, we would be able to collect information for some thousands of organisms, but this is not feasible or currently available. So, in our largest group we have a few hundreds of organism, in the smallest groups we have some tens.
- What we want to test is whether one population of organisms exhibits higher  frequencies in one group than the other population. This because we want to get a location comparison, where the measure of comparison is representative of that population Quantile comparison, skewedness, standard deviation, etc, though informative, would possibly be not as good to get insight into how different the populations are (bearing in mind our particular biological question).So we want some general measure of comparison of both populations that permits simply saying stuff like "the two populations tend to not differ greatly in *[this]* overall measure" or "this population tends to exhibit higher median/mean frequency than the other".
- I am aware that means/medians *per se* are not informative enough about the distributions of both populations. For instance, if one is heavily tailed, they may both exhibit similar medians but one of them may exhibit higher means. However, for our purposes, we believe that medians (or means if necessary) provide enough insight.

Comment: At a bare minimum, what do the non-parametric 95%-CIs look like (using the sign test)?

Comment: See here:  http://gchang.people.ysu.edu/class/s5817/L/L5817_1_4_Nonpar_OneMean.pdf

Comment: @bey - I still didnt have the time to compute them, I'm sorry. I'll come back here with more info asap

Comment: You state you want to compare groups and it appears you've decided that medians and/or means are the only the characteristics of interest.  Why?  I'm not challenging the choice.  I just always find it odd that the selection of the parameter to be tested is based on what assumptions certain statistical tests require.  I'd say "Objective first, then look for a statistical method."  Also, you've not discussed how the samples were collected.  Was this a designed experiment?  Haphazard selection of folks at a Starbucks or a Ford dealership?  Do you really have a census rather than a sample?

Comment: @JimBaldwin nice points! I added some more information. Please feel free to ask questions/criticize my points. I am probably not fully aware of all the subtleties in here since I come from a biological background, and I'm lacking statistical knowledge.

Comment: Because it seems you are interested in making more than one comparison among samples, you should consider fitting some overall model in which you could allow for different variances such as a more complex general linear model (PROC MIXED in SAS or nlme in R, for example) or taking some sort of transformation to more closely equalize the variances.  Performing multiple Welsh t-tests is not wrong but it can be very inefficient.

Comment: Search this site for `Mood's median test`. Look also here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16219/3277.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you consider relative summary effects/relative treatment effects methods of Akritas, Arnold, Brunner, etc.  The best book on the subject, generally, is [Nonparametric Analysis of Longitudinal Data in Factorial Experiments](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047144166X) by Brunner, Domhof, and Langer which is very well-written and clear.

These methods are based on modified notions of Mann-Whitney and can accommodate many of the features you mention using standard statistical software.

Answer (score 1):

One (very conservative/low power) option would be to use Mood's median test. It does not assume normality or homogeneity of variance (or at least quite robust to unequal variance).

The test is done by making a cross tabulation of the number of observations less than or equal to the overall median vs. greater than the overall median for each group. From there, you run a chi-squared test on the table. For two group comparisons and when the groups are small, I'd use Fisher's exact test instead of chi-squared.

Edit: since I don't know if Mathematica has a function for Mood's median test, if you are willing to try using R, I have code that you can use.

Edit 2: Per Sosi's request, here's the code:

```
moods.median = function(v, f, exact = FALSE) {
#v is the set of Values you want to test
#f is a Factor or grouping variable
#if you want to use Fisher's exact test, specify "exact = TRUE"

if (length(v) != length(f)) {
    stop(c("v and f must have the same length"))
}



#make a new matrix data frame
m = cbind(as.character(f),v)
colnames(m) = c("group", "value")

#get the names of the factors/groups
facs = unique(f)

#count the number of factors/groups
factorN = length(unique(f))

if (factorN < 2) {
    stop("there must be at least two groups in variable 'f'")
}

#2 rows (number of values > overall median & number of values <= overall median)
#K-many columns for each level of the factor
MoodsMedianTable = matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = factorN)

rownames(MoodsMedianTable) = c("> overall median", "<= overall median")
colnames(MoodsMedianTable) = c(facs[1:factorN])
colnames(MoodsMedianTable) = paste("Factor:",colnames(MoodsMedianTable))


#get the overall median
overallmedian = median(v)


#put the following into the 2 by K table:
for(j in 1:factorN){ #for each factor level

    g = facs[j] #assign a temporary "group name"

    #count the number of observations in the factor that are greater than
    #the overall median and save it to the table
    MoodsMedianTable[1,j] = sum(m[,2][ which(m[,1]==g)] > overallmedian)

    #count the number of observations in the factor that are less than
    # or equal to the overall median and save it to the table
    MoodsMedianTable[2,j] = sum(m[,2][ which(m[,1]==g)] <= overallmedian)

}

print(MoodsMedianTable)

if(exact == FALSE){return(chisq.test(MoodsMedianTable))}

if(exact == TRUE){return(list(
    chisq.test(MoodsMedianTable),
    fisher.test(MoodsMedianTable)))
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I appreciate if you can show me the R code.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is that you have the order of your tests backwards.  If the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test shows that the samples come from a similar distribution, then use the t-test, otherwise use the Mann-Whitney U test.

For unequal variances, there is a procedure by Fligner and Policello (1981) who describe a methodology which can be employed for computing an adjusted U statistic if the homogeneity of variance assumption underlying the Mann-Whitney U test is violated.  The reference I have for the Fligner-Policello test is Fligner, M. A. & Policello, II, G.E. (1981).  Robust rank procedures for the Behrens-Fisher problem.  Journal of the American Statistical Association, 76, 162-174.

the Welch's T-Test seems to be implemented in the EqualVariances->False option in the MeanDifferenceCl.

EqualVariances  False   whether the unknown population variances are assumed equal -- Option for MeanDifferenceCI.

- "Confidence intervals for the difference between means are also based
  on Student's  distribution if the variances are not known. If the
  variances are assumed equal, MeanDifferenceCI is based on Student's 
  distribution with Length[list1]+Length[list2]-2 degrees of freedom.
  If the population variances are not assumed equal, Welch's
  approximation for the degrees of freedom is used".  See: 
  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/HypothesisTesting/tutorial/HypothesisTesting.html

Comment: The `Kolmogorov-Smirnov` tests for similarity of shape between distributions (required assumption for the Mann-Whitney U test), not normality (one of the required assumptions for the t-test). 
I'm not sure whether the `MeanDifferenceCI` or `MeanDifferenceTest` is what is needed to compare the two populations medians or means, I'll need to read about it

Comment: I wonder if what is said `If the population variances are not assumed equal, Welch's approximation for the degrees of freedom is used` is also implemented in the `LocationTest` and `MannWhitneyTest`. Both of these, or at least the former, test for population variance, so it would make sense that they would use this same approximation!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  In SAS there is the Kolmogorov D Statistic for Normality - which is what I was referring to.  For the procedure to calculate the Kolmogorov D Statistic see this link @ https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect037.htm

Comment: You are right! I need to rephrase: I perform the Kolmogorov-Smirnov using both data entries to test whether the first exhibits a distribution similar to the second. If I only used one data entry a normal distribution would be assumed. Editing main text

Comment: In what way would a t-test compare *medians*, given that neither distribution would necessarily be symmetric?

Comment: @whuber I am not sure I am understanding your question, but I had stated in the main text that I was aware that Welch's t-test would be comparing means and not medians

Comment: Sosi, my comment was addressed to Steven Anderson, whose answer advocates using a t-test by default, regardless of the shape of the distribution.  You can do a lot better than this using standard nonparametric procedures.